# Multi select drop down in an ag grid

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, ag-grid, multi-select, angular-ngselect

I am trying to implement a multi select drop down inside a ag grid, but i am unable get anything.

My code is as below.

In app.componet.ts i have(Inside a columnDefs)

```
{headerName: 'product', field:'product', editable: this.editFunctionAll(this),cellRenderer: 
"productComponent" , width:120},
```

Then i have another component named as productComponent and i have as below:

```
@Component({
selector: 'lma-child',
template: `
<ng-select [items]="cities2"
               bindLabel="name"
               bindValue="id"
               [multiple]="true"
               placeholder="Select cities"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCityIds">
</ng-select>
`});

 export class ProductComponent  {
 cities2 = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Vilnius'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Kaunas'},
   {id: 3, name: 'Pavilnys', disabled: true},
   {id: 4, name: 'Pabradė'},
   {id: 5, name: 'Klaipėda'}
 ];
 }
```

Here i am getting the ag grid cell as a just editable field.Not able catch whats happening. Please help me in this.

Regards!

Comment: Okay sure. I will post in some time.

Comment: I am just facing bit problem in adding it in stackbiltz, can you please tell me is the method i am doing is a right one?am i missing something here.?

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk so that others can help you easily.